# Setup USB File Transfer - Android on Galaxy S7 to Windows 7/8/10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, usb, android

So, I want to transfer files from my Galaxy S7 Edge Android to Windows 10.

The instructions are to connect the USB cable and wait for a dropdown notification that says, 'USB CHARGING OPTIONS' but fails to appear / does not show notification / just charges without notifying me.

I want to transfer pictures and transfer movies from my phone to my PC. Without that dropdown, it fails to show on windows box.

Answer (score 0):

((   TLDR; developer options.  ))

Details:  Unplug your phone from the USB cable. IMPORTANT.

Pull down top option bar, then gear icon for settings. Scroll to bottom to see 'Developer Options'. Scroll down thru that to "USB Configuration", press that and hold it, choose "MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)"

OPTIONALLY, doublecheck by repeating path and seeing that it's set correctly.

RESTART YOUR PHONE. Yes, necessary with developer options.

When phone starts, unlock. Plug in USB cable. YOU WILL NOW SEE DROPDOWN NOTIFICATION. Click on the USB charging option and set to media transfer.

you should hear windows chirp to say you've connected a new device.

Bingo! you're ready.

NOTES: don't transfer off more than your pictures and videos. The other non-picture and non-video files are important to Android, deleting them could harm your system.